# Get selected radio button value from "for loop"

Tags: javascript, html

I need a help from you all. In my website, I am generating different colour shades from a selected color. Till here it works fine but after generating different shades, when I select a radio button associated with shades, I get value of first shade no matter how many random radio buttons I select

And the color hex value is coming from array... I want to get the value of selected radio button and store it into html5 localstorage. localstorage works fine if i enter simple text instead of selected radio button value. Please have a look

I am positing my code below:

```
function makeTableRowColors(colors, displayType)
{
   var tableRow = "<tr>";

   for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) 
   {
      if (displayType == "colors")
      {
         tableRow += "<td style=\"background-color:" + "#" + colors[i].toString(16) + ";width:85px;height:75px;border-radius:5px;\";><input type='radio' class='ShadeRadioButtons' name='rsSelections' style='position:relative;top:-24px;' value='#"+colors[i].toString(16).toUpperCase()+"'></td>";
      }
   else
   {
      tableRow += "<td class=\"rgb-value\">#" + colors[i].toString(16).toUpperCase() + "</td>"; 

   }
}

 tableRow += "</tr>";
 return tableRow;
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves No Sir. Its in pure javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your HTML or the localStorage code you are attempting, but the code should make sure to get the value property, as in:

```
 radButton.value
```

This code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/10factxr/1/

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks mate. It worked. I was unnecessarily going after localstorage. +1000

Comment: I clicked on the up arrow and it turned orange with 1 in middle.